# Expected lexical element not found

Tags: sql, ms-access

Every time I used 'Count()' to count the duplicate PointIDs' on the query I get this error.

I have narrowed down the problem is with Count() function, used MAX() with Group by and didn't have any problem. This is on access database populated using ODBC connection. All the help is appriciated - I have done all the research and this is my last online resort.

```
SELECT Event1.PointID, Event1.LogTimeStamp, Count(Event1.PointID) AS acount
FROM Event1
GROUP BY Event1.PointID, Event1.LogTimeStamp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you actually want to return all duplicate records which is a 2 step operation.

Step 1 get find the ids which are duplicated

```
   SELECT Event1.PointID, Count(*) AS NumOfRecords
   FROM Event1
   GROUP BY Event1.PointID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Step 2 join that result back to the original table to find the records

```
SELECT e.*, d.NumOfRecords
FROM
    Event1 e
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Event1.PointID, Count(*) AS NumOfRecords
       FROM Event1
       GROUP BY Event1.PointID
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) d
    ON e.PointId = d.PointId
```

Comment: Step 1 works pretty good - gives me the counts but Step 2 doesn't return the NumOfRecords col. It just dumbs the whole record from the original data.   Thanks for all your help and time. Regards, -aK>

Comment: yeah it looked like you wanted the records them selves.  you can add NumOfRecords into step 2 easily it will just be a repeated value for each of the actual counts so in step 2 just append ,d.NumOfRecords to SELECT e.*  line so it reads SELECT e.*, d.NumOfRecords

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard syntax for what you want to do:

```
SELECT Event1.PointID, Event1.LogTimeStamp, Count(*) AS acount
FROM Event1
GROUP BY Event1.PointID, Event1.LogTimeStamp;
```